# Not able to write #include statements properly in Geany IDE

Tags: c++, c, geany

Whenever I want to include a header in my source code, the IDE doesn't allow me to type the `.h` extension. If I type `<stdio.h>` it accepts only `<stdio>`, and I'm unable to type any further. I made no changes to the default settings built-in to the IDE. I am using the latest version `1.37.1`. I have to manually #include header files from `Edit > Insert "include<..>"`. Any suggestions on how I can disable this behaviour of the IDE?

Comment: Perhaps the IDE is in "angry c++ mode" and only lets you include the correct headers, like `<cstdio>`? What's the full name of your source code file? Is it ending with `.c` or `.cpp` (or anything else that indicates that you are making a c++ program)? Can you include headers using `"stdio.h"` instead of `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No I'm not able to include files using quotes as well. I also found out that I'm not able to type other file extensions in quotes, like if I want to write some output to a text file, when i type the file name followed by ```.txt``` in quotes like ```"text.txt"```, it accepts only ```"testxt"```, it skips the ```.t``` part

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a terrible IDE. Do you have to use that particular IDE?

Comment: Please find out your configuration for "drop rest of word for auto completion" (within editor completion preferences). It could be active and I suspect you do not want it active. If this does not help, but seems kind of interesting, read for inspiration https://www.geany.org/manual/1.23.1/index.html#editor-completions-preferences and bearby sibling pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider this to be just on the right side of the on/offtopic definition, using the exception for "tools regularily used by programmers".
So I recommend to find out your configuration for "drop rest of word for auto completion" (within editor completion preferences). It could be active and I suspect you do not want it active.

If this does not help, but seems kind of interesting, read for inspiration https://www.geany.org/manual/1.23.1/index.html#editor-completions-preferences and bearby sibling pages.

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing that but it didn't work. I tried re-installing the IDE, still didn't work. Finally, I got it to work by changing my system keyboard layout to English US. Previously, the language was English India, but the keyboard was correct - Eng US. And I had no problems with typing programs in Visual Studio all this while. Maybe some setting in the IDE that expects both the system language as well as the keyboard to be Eng US has caused this problem. I hope anyone who came across a similar issue try changing the keyboard layout.

Comment: That is an interesting contribution. Turn it into an answer to your own question. You can even accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I might have phrased confusingly. What I meant was that your own comment on my answer seems so much of a helpful insight (and to you personally the actual solution) that I would support you in creating your own answer post to your own question. And I wanted to point out that it is perfectly matching StackOverflow ideas and goals that you then accept your own answer. I worry that you misunderstood me to ask you to accept my answer. If you understood my meaning and simply wanted to honor my answer as helpful, though not to the point, I thank you. Still, make your own answer please.